# Dojo DnD Move Node Programmatically

Tags: dojo, drag-and-drop

I would like to know if there is a way to move the node programmatically in dojo Dnd? The reason is I would like to revert the changes to the drag and drop when the web service call triggered a failed save on the database. Here is what I have so far.

In my code, the node Id seems to be unrecognized by the dojo.dnd.Container.DelItem. I cannot just use the selected item on the target because this is a asynchronous webservice function callback. So the user may be selecting another node on the container when this is called.

```
function OnMoveWSComplete(strResult) {
    var resultObj = eval('(' + strResult + ')');
    var sourceContainer = eval('(' + objResult.sourceContainerId + ')');
    var targetContainer = eval('(' + objResult.targetContainerId + ')');

    var targetNodes = targetContainer.getAllNodes();
    for (var iNode = 0; iNode < targetNodes.length; iNode++) {
        var currId = getLastIdFromStr(targetNodes[iNode].id);

        if (currId == resultObj.Id) {
            var targetN = targetNodes[iNode];

            var Name = targetNodes[iNode].childNodes[0].nodeValue;

            targetContainer.delItem(targetNodes[iNode].id);
            var origData = { Id: resultObj.Id, Name: Name };
            sourceContainer.insertNodes(true, origData);

            break;
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**: Solution (Thanks Eugene Lazutkin) [2009/11/30]:

```
/**
* Move one node from one container to the other
*/
function moveNode(nodeId, sourceContainer, targetContainer) {
    var node = dojo.byId(nodeId);

    // Save the data
    var saveData = sourceContainer.map[nodeId].data;

    // Do the move
    sourceContainer.parent.removeChild(node);
    targetContainer.parent.appendChild(node);

    // Sync the DOM object → map
    sourceContainer.sync();
    targetContainer.sync();

    // Restore data for recreation of data
    targetContainer.map[nodeId].data = saveData;
}
```

Comment: How do you invocate OnMoveWSComplete after the DnD is complete? I've created a function that suscribes to /dnd/drop, but when it is invocated the DnD is not made yet, so the reverse of the change fails. Can you give me an example of the invocation?
Thanks.
Jose

Comment: Jose, when I susbscribe to the Dnd drop event I just used connect. It works fine with me. 

dojo.connect(containerId, 'onDrop', onDropSave);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you assume that `delItem` removes physical nodes. Take a look at the [documentation](http://docs.dojocampus.org/dojo/dnd#public-methods-and-attributes) — probably you want to move nodes between containers instead of deleting them from the map. One simple way to do that just to move DOM nodes between containers, and call `sync()` on both containers.

**Addition**: Here is a super-simple pseudocode-like example:

```
function move(node, source, target){
  // normalize node and/or node id
  node = dojo.byId(node);
  // move it physically from one parent to another
  // (from target to source) adding to the end
  target.parent.appenChild(node);
  // now it is moved from source to target
  // let's synchronize both dojo.dnd.Source's
  source.sync();
  target.sync();
}
```

Or something along these lines should work. The important pieces:

- Move node from one parent to another using any DOM operations you deem appropriate. I used `appendChild()`, but you can use `insertBefore()`, or anything else.
- Synchronize both sources involved after the move.

Obviously it works if both sources use nodes of the same type and structure. If not, you should do something more complex, e.g., move everything you need emulating a real DnD move by publishing topics described in the documentation.

Comment: I actually already did the sync() too but it did not work. By the way, if remove then add is not recommended, could you point me to the move function?  I could not find any function in documentation for that.

Comment: There is no special API to move nodes between sources. Did you try the one I sketched out for you in my answer (the last sentence)? OK, I'll add an example.

Comment: I just read the source code of sync. it seems the reason why the delItem() and sync() call does not work is because delItem() deletes from the map and sync() copies the actual DOM nodes back to the map structure which actually negates the delItem().

Comment: Thanks your suggestion worked, I just need to save the map data so I could recreate the node again.

Answer (score 2):

I have this function which moves selected nodes by button click:

```
source.forInItems(dojo.hitch(this, function(item, id, map) {
  if (dojo.hasClass(id, "dojoDndItemAnchor")) {
    target.onDrop(source, [ dojo.byId(id) ], false);
    dojo.removeClass(id, "dojoDndItemAnchor");
  }
}));
```

`onDrop()` is an overridable method, which is called upon item drop, and by default calls to method `onDropExternal(source, nodes, copy)`.

Answer (score 0):

I am doing the same thing right now. I was able to solve by doing the following.

- Set the dnd/Source autoSync property to true

`<div data-dojo-type="dojo.dnd.Source" accept="widget" class="source" data-dojo-props="autoSync: true">`

After dragging it looses the dndtype so I had to re-add it using client side code. Also I remove the dojoDndItemAnchor class after drop.

`$(node).removeClass('dojoDndItemAnchor').attr('dndtype', 'widget');`